# In Scala, create a stream based on previous value and a second stream

Tags: scala, stream

I can't come up with a way to combine these into a single stream. I have:

```
val loop: Stream[Bar] = Stream(bar1, bar2, bar3) #::: loop
val init: Foo = new Foo()
def nextFoo(foo: Foo, bar: Bar): Foo = { ... }
```

What I want is a stream like this:

```
Stream(
    init, 
    nextFoo(init, bar1), 
    nextFoo(nextFoo(init, bar1), bar2),
    nextFoo(nextFoo(nextFoo(init, bar1), bar2), bar3),
    nextFoo(nextFoo(nextFoo(nextFoo(init, bar1), bar2), bar3), bar1),
    ...
)
```

or, in words, each element depends on the next element in `loop` and the previous element in my output stream.

It's a chicken-and-egg problem - I feel like I want to `zip` the second stream with the first one but I can't create the first stream (e.g., with `Stream.iterate`) without zipping on the second.

Is this possible with just the functions in Scala's collections library? I could probably put something together with `(new Iterator { ... }).toStream` but would want to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With "fake" Bar and Foo that will contains list of "processed" bars it will look like this:

```
  case class Bar(s: String)
  val bar1 = Bar("bar1")
  val bar2 = Bar("bar2")
  val bar3 = Bar("bar3")

  case class Foo(bars: Seq[Bar])


  val loop: Stream[Bar] = Stream(bar1, bar2, bar3) #::: loop
  val init: Foo = new Foo(Nil)
  def nextFoo(foo: Foo, bar: Bar): Foo =
    foo.copy(bars = foo.bars :+ bar)

  val foos: Stream[Foo] = Stream(init) #::: foos.zip(loop).map({ case (f, b) => nextFoo(f, b) })

  foos.take(10).toList.foreach(println)
```

Result:

```
Foo(List())
Foo(List(Bar(bar1)))
Foo(List(Bar(bar1), Bar(bar2)))
Foo(List(Bar(bar1), Bar(bar2), Bar(bar3)))
Foo(List(Bar(bar1), Bar(bar2), Bar(bar3), Bar(bar1)))
Foo(List(Bar(bar1), Bar(bar2), Bar(bar3), Bar(bar1), Bar(bar2)))
Foo(List(Bar(bar1), Bar(bar2), Bar(bar3), Bar(bar1), Bar(bar2), Bar(bar3)))
Foo(List(Bar(bar1), Bar(bar2), Bar(bar3), Bar(bar1), Bar(bar2), Bar(bar3), Bar(bar1)))
Foo(List(Bar(bar1), Bar(bar2), Bar(bar3), Bar(bar1), Bar(bar2), Bar(bar3), Bar(bar1), Bar(bar2)))
Foo(List(Bar(bar1), Bar(bar2), Bar(bar3), Bar(bar1), Bar(bar2), Bar(bar3), Bar(bar1), Bar(bar2), Bar(bar3)))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I had just come up with an algorithm that also has the same result: `Stream.iterate((init, loop)) { case (f, b #:: bs) => (nextFoo(f, b), bs) }.map (_._1)`. To me, yours is less clumsy. How would you compare your solution to this one?

Comment: I've made an edit to the solution - you can use `init #:: ...` instead of `Stream(init) #::: ...`